# Cannot pull images from Kubernetes from a private registry with self-sign certificates if I change CA

Tags: ssl-certificate, kubernetes, certificate-authority

I created a private registry with a self-sign certificate
If I'll try to pull the image from it w/o importing the CA into trusted certificates, it will fail.

If I'll try to update trusted certificates after a first try w/o it it will continue to fail. What I need to to is to destroy the server, start from strach, import the certificate and try after that [on a fresh machine]. In this scenario it will work BUT

If I'll recreate the registry with another CA, importing it into the machine and trust it, it will not work anymore no matter what.
Why is that and how I can fix this?

So step by step what I'm doing:

1. Create machine A with a private registry and self sign certificate
2. Create machine B with K8s
3. Try on machine B to pull image from machine A - it will fail with `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`
4. Import CA from machine A [priv registry] into machine B and trust it
5. Pulling images still failing
6. Destroy machine B and start from scratch
7. Import CA from from machine A [priv registry] into machine B and trust it
8. Try to pull image on machine B - is working
9. Destroy machine A and recreate the private registry with another CA
10. Import the new CA into machine B and trust it
11. Try to pull images on machine B from machine A [priv registry] - will fail and the only solution would be to destroy machine B again
    `tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying t o verify candidate authority certificate "CA ORGANIZATION NAME")`

BUT: I will lose all my work with images already imported and so on ... how and why is happening this and how can be fixed?

LE: If I'll restart the server it will work in both scenarios were failed, but this is not something that I want to do [restarting machine]. Is it there another solution [not restarting k8s as well ...]

Comment: I still don't know why is this happening. What I do is I'll not regenerate the CA every time. I'll use same all the time [priv key will be same as well] and based on it I'll create the certs

Answer (score 0):

You can try to restart the service depending on what you're using container application instead of restarting the whole instance

You can use any of these commands:

```
systemctl restart containerd
```

```
service docker restart
```

Or you can create a new registry and upload your existing images